# I want to play my guitar via iRig through my computer with my iPhone 4

Tags: iphone

I want to play my guitar via iRig through my computer with my iPhone 4. The earphones are uncomfortable, and the wires keep tangling with the guitar. I've connected my iPhone to the computer, but what do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely postively must play it through your computer (see below for better options), you could try installing XBMC on your computer and using AirPlay off your iPhone to play through your computer speakers.

Better options: attach the speakers on your computer (if you have external speakers) to the headphone jack; get a 1/4 inch to 1/8 inch adapter and plug it into the microphone port on your computer, then <s>pirate</s> acquire Ableton Live; get a decent audio interface for your computer, you'll get way better sound out of it.

Comment: I was hoping there wasa simple way to do it; I was given the iRig as a present by my kids, and am struggling with it a bit. The computer has a Realtek Audio Manager; could that help?

Answer (score 0):

In addition, take a look at Airfoil.  it allows streaming wireless audio from a mac to a phone and vice versa.  It supports any application, including Ableton.  And has some advanced options for MIDI mapping etc. You'd need Airoil and Airfoil speakers on your computer.  Just Speakers on the the iPhone.

it will set you back $25 or so, but it's been a lifesaver for me. And still is!